# Python 3.6 windows cannot use packages installed from pip

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

I cannot use any packages installed using pip on python, it says no such package as x installed despite when listing packages using help('modules') it lists package x as installed.
Package trying to use: discord
Error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bob Ross\Desktop\Twitch bot\discord.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\Bob Ross\Desktop\Twitch bot\discord.py", line 2, in <module>
    from discord.ext.commands import Bot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.ext'; 'discord' is not a package`

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
my_bot = Bot(command_prefix="!")
@my_bot.event
async def on_read():
    print("Client logged in")
@my_bot.command()
async def hello(*args):
    return await my_bot.say("Hello, world!")
my_bot.run("{token omitted}")
```

I am running windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your script to other name than `discord.py`; that prevents import of the module you want because your module is imported instead.

Also make sure there's no `C:\Users\Bob Ross\Desktop\Twitch bot\discord.pyc` remain in the directory.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! It seems so obvious that would prevent the import now. Thank you!

Comment: @8o7wer, Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this helped you, you can tell the community so by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235).

Comment: I was going to but It restricted me from accepting within 8 minutes and i then forgot about it.